# Google Cloud Messaging ошибка: Unable to instantiate receiver .GCMBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Я импортировал библиотеку google-play-services_lib из SDK in в свое приложение,и следовал этой инструкции http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/ , но у меня вылазиет ошибка "Unable to instantiate receiver .GCMBroadcastReceiver" . Как это пофиксить?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.games.zx"
    ...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.games.zx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.games.zx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
...
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.games.zx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
...
```

Я пытался делать так:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.games.zx.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
...
```

Но это не не помогло
[image]

Ошибки:

> 04-16 14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-16 14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.games.zx.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.games.zx.GcmBroadcastReceiver 04-16 14:17:57.612:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2383)
>   04-16 14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
>   04-16 14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 04-16 14:17:57.612:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-16 14:17:57.612:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   04-16 14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-16 14:17:57.612:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27756): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.games.zx.GcmBroadcastReceiver 04-16 14:17:57.612:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   04-16 14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 04-16
>   14:17:57.612: E/AndroidRuntime(27756):    at

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("myLog", "Enter to receiver");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прописать полный путь до сервиса.

Не **.GcmBroadcastReceiver**, а **com.games.zx.GcmBroadcastReceiver**.

Comment: Я пробовал так делать, все равно та же самая ошибка

Comment: @Vlad161 чтобы что-то наверняка сказать, надо код смотреть =/

Comment: @Suvitruf какой именно класс интересует?

Comment: @Suvitruf  Весь код выложить не могу, начальник не оценит. Как с тобой можно связаться? Вк, icq, skype? Может это быть из-за того что импортировал как то не так? Я скачал в SDK Google play services , импортировал его, и в properties - Android снизу выбрал этот поект. В том проекте, что я импортировал Google play services, там же properties - Android стоит галочка Is library (она должна стоять). Уже третий день пытаюсь исправить, никак не получается :( Ответы со stackoverflow не подходят

Comment: @Vlad161 я там много чего дописывал сам, чтобы нормально сервис работал.

Comment: @Suvitruf А что именно дописывал? В ресивере, СервисИнтенте? а можешь дать все таки свой контакт? Хоть краем глаза посмотришь, может увидишь, что не так

Comment: @Vlad161 http://vk.com/id692904